# Keep a batch-file after the "start" command is used

Tags: batch-file

so I have been making a batch-file that is a collection of websites so when the user selects what website he wants to visit the start command is used to open iexplorer.exe. But the batch-file is closed and then the website opens. Is there any way to keep it from closing? This is the code I am currently using:

```
start iexplorer.exe www.website.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work add `pause>nul` to the end of your batch file:

```
start iexplorer.exe www.website.com
pause>nul
```